# Incremental update of specific columns of data in dbt

Tags: dbt

Given a table with say, 20 columns, my current model already inserts all the records into the table. However, I'd like to focus my incremental updates on a couple of columns specifically.

For example, given the following table model. I'd like to incrementally update only column C with new values when new values are available, not delete and re-insert the whole row which is more costly on indexes / performance perspective.

Existing:

| id | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | X | 1 |
| n2 | Y | 2 |
| n3 | Z | 3 |

New:

| id | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | X | 1.2 |
| n2 | Y | 2.1 |
| n3 | Z | 3.5 |

Comment: To my knowledge, this functionality doesn't exist yet but there's an open issue for it here - https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/1862

Comment: Hey man! Were you able to solve this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

It seems this feature will be added to the next version of dbt (v0.20.0). But just to summarize, a new option (**merge_update_columns**) to specify the columns will be available in the model’s config block.

```py
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'incremental',
    unique_key = 'id',
    merge_update_columns = ['c'],
    ...
  )
}}

select ...
```

Check the docs for more details:
https://next.docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#strategy-specific-configs

Comment: Hello! Any news with that?

Comment: Hey, this option is already available in dbt >= v0.20 -- Be aware it's supported on adapters that have the ` merge`  strategy (Snowflake, BigQuery, Databricks, etc)

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#strategy-specific-configs