# Incremental model update for Postgres in DBT

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, dbt

Disclaimer - A newbie in DBT

Problem 1 -
I want to send data from AWS S3 -> Postgres.
Using Airbyte for the same.
It transforms the data in S3 to a raw table(JSONB column containing data) in Postgres to which I apply dbt to get the actual result in another table.

This is the DBT code that extracts data from raw table to an actual table.
In the data 'seller_id' is being passed as env var and is not available in the raw data and will be acting as a Foreign key.

```
 {{ config
    (
        materialized='incremental',
        indexes = [
            {'columns': ['article_type', 'seller_id']}
        ],
        unique_key = ['seller_id', 'brand', 'master_category'],
        on_conflict='update'
    )
}}

with __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab1 as (
    
    select
        jsonb_extract_path_text(_airbyte_data, 'brand') as brand,
        jsonb_extract_path_text(_airbyte_data, 'master_category') as master_category,
        jsonb_extract_path_text(_airbyte_data, 'article_type') as article_type,
        jsonb_extract_path_text(_airbyte_data, 'commission inc tax') as commission_inc_tax,
        jsonb_extract_path_text(_airbyte_data, 'article_level') as article_level,
        _airbyte_ab_id,
        _airbyte_emitted_at,
        now() as _airbyte_normalized_at
    from "revenue_recon".public._airbyte_raw_myntra_commission_rule as table_alias
    where 1 = 1
    ),  __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab2 as (
    
    select
        cast(brand as text) as brand,
        cast(master_category as text) as master_category,
        cast(article_type as text) as article_type,
        cast(commission_inc_tax as numeric(10, 2)) as commission_inc_tax,
        cast(article_level as integer) as article_level,
        _airbyte_ab_id,
        _airbyte_emitted_at,
        now() as _airbyte_normalized_at
    from __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab1
    where 1 = 1
    ),  __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab3 as (
    
    select
        md5('abc') as _airbyte_myntra_commission_rule_hashid,
        tmp.*
    from __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab2 tmp
    where 1 = 1
    )
    select
        {{ var('seller_id') }} as seller_id,
        brand,
        master_category,
        article_type,
        commission_inc_tax,
        article_level,
        _airbyte_ab_id,
        _airbyte_emitted_at,
        now() as _airbyte_normalized_at,
        _airbyte_myntra_commission_rule_hashid
    from __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab3
```

The issue that I am facing is
suppose I transform the data wrt seller_id 1. Then all the rows will contain seller_id as 1. Now when I upload another batch of data and then again transform with seller_id 2, it replaces the original seller_id 1 with 2. Solved this issue by adding seller_id in the unique_key constraints.

Now I can see the original data with seller_id 1. But it has created another issue.
Suppose earlier the data inserted was

seller_id brand master_category

```
 1    brand1   mc1

 1    brand1   mc2

 1    brand1   mc3
```

Next uploaded data was

```
 2   brand2   mc1

 2   brand2   mc2

 2   brand2   mc3
```

Now DBT earlier had 3 rows when I had transformed with seller_id 1. But after transforming it with seller_id 2 the total rows in the table grow to 9 instead of 6.
The rows contain this data

```
1 brand1 mc1

1 brand1 mc2

1 brand1 mc3

2 brand1 mc1

2 brand1 mc2

2 brand1 mc3

2 brand2 mc1

2 brand2 mc2

2 brand2 mc3
```

Dont understand why its creating those 3 additional rows -

```
2 brand1 mc1

2 brand1 mc2

2 brand1 mc3
```

even after having an incremental model.

What I can think is, the raw table has data for both seller_id 1->brand1 and seller_id2->brand2. And when I'm transforming the table wrt seller_id 2, its considering the data with seller_id1 also.

Problem 2 -

Wanted to track the history of data uploaded. Like what data was uploaded when and when the same unique identifier data was uploaded again.

Tried to solve it by adding an is_active, created_at and updated_at field. Whenever a data conflict occurs, it will update the previous record to is_active -> False and updated_at with current timestamp and insert the new data with is_active -> True

```
    {{ config
    (
        materialized='incremental',
        indexes = [
            {'columns': ['article_type', 'seller_id']}
        ],
        unique_key = ['seller_id', 'brand', 'master_category', 'is_active', 'updated_at'],
        on_conflict='(seller_id, brand, master_category) DO UPDATE SET is_active = FALSE, updated_at = NOW() WHERE excluded.is_active = TRUE'
    )
}}
```

Saw this answer but it doesnt support postgres it seems ([Incremental update of specific columns of data in dbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974445/incremental-update-of-specific-columns-of-data-in-dbt))

Any other recommended approach?

Problem 3 -

Since the data in the table will be huge and the querying will be based on the seller_id, its wise to have partitions on seller_id. Tried it with this code but it didnt create any.

```
{{ config
    (
        materialized='incremental',
        partition_by=['seller_id'],
        indexes = [
            {'columns': ['article_type', 'seller_id']}
        ],
        unique_key = ['seller_id', 'brand', 'master_category'],
        on_conflict='update'
    )
}}
```

What I think from a non-dbt perspective is we will have to create a procedure that has a trigger on before inserting any data. That procedure will check if there is a partition on seller_id and if not then create it. Do let me know if I am missing or wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problems 1,2

First one was due to a unique constraint issue, added suitable columns to have a better unique constraints

Second one was solved by another approach. Avoided inserting new data with is_active fields as it could have resulted in huge data. Solved it by updating the existing data with the new ones. partition_by clause should have the unique constraints.

```
    ranked_data as (
    select
        {{ var('seller_id') }} as _seller_id,
        brand,
        master_category,
        article_type,
        commission_inc_tax,
        gender,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        _airbyte_ab_id,
        _airbyte_emitted_at,
        row_number() over (
            partition by
                {{ var('seller_id') }},
                brand,
                master_category,
                article_type
            order by
                _airbyte_emitted_at desc
        ) as row_num
    from __dbt__cte__myntra_commission_rule_ab2
)
select
    row_number() over (order by _seller_id, _company_id, brand, master_category, article_type) as _id,
    _seller_id,
    now() as _created_on,
    brand,
    master_category,
    article_type,
    commission_inc_tax,
    gender,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    _airbyte_ab_id,
    _airbyte_emitted_at
from ranked_data where row_num=1
```